# Пароль для админ панели

Tags: mysqli, php

Возник вопрос, при создании входа для админ панели. Можно ли использовать куки, для запоминания администратора, голыми ? то есть без обработки кроме md5 шифрования. Мое мнение: я думаю что не надо. Подскажите как лучше ? безопасность тут лежит на стороне админов. Если не так, то что лучше использовать ?

Comment: > то есть без обработки кроме md5 шифрования

хэширование это **не** шифрование

> Можно ли использовать куки, для запоминания администратора, голыми?

long story short: нет, все хранится в сессии, в куках только идентификатор сессии и хрень, не имеющая никакого значения типа последнего времени входа для надписи "привет, рады что не виделись целый день, пожалуйста, закройте дверь с той стороны", в сессии также записан как минимум айпи для предотвращения кражи сессии. При неверном айпи сессия не терминируется, но движок ведет себя так, будто перед ним гость.

Comment: спасибо, ошибся с хешированием :}

Comment: > При неверном айпи сессия не терминируется, но движок ведет себя так, будто перед ним гость.

надо делать опциональным, т.к. очень раздражает иногда. особенно когда whitelist.

Comment: Создайте поле session в таблице юзерс и долбитесь по тому хешу который там записан!

------------------------------------------

Если md5 не сошелся клином, есть еще sha1 а еще лучше crypt.

Comment: в php 5 уже давно есть http://ru2.php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в сессиях обычно хранят текущий id сессии ( который включает в себя зашифрованное (дважды `trim(md5(md5($id)))` по md5 связку id + соль.  id - создается строка в таблице где логин и даташтамп входа, true/false - авторизации. Солью может быть : дата и время (активная сессия на n минут, с обновление после каждого запроса), как тут писали ip адрес, к примеру браузер, дополнительно просто мусорное значение, но как совет не делайте его постоянным, например квадрат даты, или еще  чего нибудь, всё от фантазии зависит

в кукизах я храню какую тему выбрал пользователь, какой язык использовать ( но есть и язык по умолчанию)

Comment: > trim(md5(md5($id)))

но зачем?

Comment: избавление от паранойи

Comment: @shilgen

тут даже три зачем

1) зачем тримать  
2) зачем хэшить именно два раза? Или мы просто скрываем от человеческого глаза (однократно), либо вводим боевую машину на 5000 итераций (я не шучу - посмотрите `crypt()`)  
3) смысл этой операции? Если *отступник* увел сессию по ее ключу, то в ней окажется именно этот самый ключ, нет?